# UISlider default thumbcolor

Tags: ios, uislider

I have UISlider when I move thumb, I did change thumbcolor:

```
slider.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(145/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1];
```

I wonder how I did change color to default when I press Button reset?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender
{
[self.slider setThumbTintColor:nil];
}
```